Every well-ordered set is order isomorphic to an ordinal
I have attempted a constructive proof of this theorem, but I am not sure if it is correct, and how to complete it. As follows :
Let $\langle A, \leq \rangle$ be well-ordered. $(\leftarrow, a)^{A}_{\leq}$ denotes the initial segment for $a \in A$. Let $ \alpha = \lbrace (\leftarrow, a) \ | \ a \in A \rbrace \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ and consider $\langle \alpha, \subseteq \rangle$. Define :
$$f : A \to \alpha$$
$$f(a) = (\leftarrow, a)$$
Then, this defines an order-isomorphism :
$(\leftarrow, a)_{\subseteq}^{\alpha} \subseteq (\leftarrow,
    b)_{\subseteq}^{\alpha} \iff a \leq b$, with equality if and only if $a=b$.
Now, if we show $\alpha$ to be an ordinal, we are done. Unfortunately, I am stuck here. It is straightforward to show that $\alpha$ is well-ordered :

$\alpha$ is totally ordered by $\subseteq$.
Given $\beta \subseteq \alpha$, consider $f^{-1}(\beta) \subseteq A$. Then, $f^{-1}(\beta)$ has a minimum by well-ordering of $A$. If $a = \min (f^{-1}(\beta))$, then $f(a)$ is minimum of $\beta$.

Now, we are supposed to take an element of $\alpha$ and show it is equal to an initial segment. Please help me with that.

What is your definition of “ordinal”?

An ordinal is a well-ordered set $\langle A \leq \rangle$ s.t $\forall a \in A, a = (\leftarrow, a)$.

If I understand your notations correctly, I am not convinced that you set $\alpha$ is an ordinal. Just take the construction you did for simply ${ 2.1, \pi }$ with the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$. It is a finite totally ordered set, therefore it is well ordered. Now by your construction, $\alpha$ consists of $\emptyset$ and  ${2.1}$. For it to be an ordinal, the set ${2.1 }$ would have to contain $\emptyset$ and that isn't the case.

As pointed out by user Keen in the comments, your construction won't work, because your $\alpha$ is not necessarily an ordinal. You indeed have that $\alpha$ is wellordered, and that $\alpha$ is order isomorphic to $A$. However, for $\alpha$ to be an ordinal, you need that every element of $\alpha$ is an initial segment of $\alpha$ itself. Unfortunately, you only have that every element of $\alpha$ is an initial segment of $A$, which is unrelated and actually undesirable.
To prove that this approach doesn't work, take any object $x\neq \emptyset$, and any second object $y\neq x$. Now consider the set $A=\{x,y\}$, and totally order $A$ using $x<y$. Clearly $(A,\leq)$ is order isomorphic to $2$, and is thus a wellorder. However, according to your construction, we have $\alpha=\{\emptyset, \{x\}\}$, and this cannot possibly be an ordinal unless $x=\emptyset$, which was denied by construction.

The simplest way to construct the isomorphism you need is via transfinite recursion on $A$. Recursively define a function $F$ with domain $A$, in accordance with $F(a)=\{F(b) : a>b\in A\}$. An induction proves that each $F(a)$ is in fact an ordinal, and thus $F:A\to\mathbf{Ord}$ is strictly increasing. From there, a similar argument shows that the image of $F$ is an ordinal, from which we can see that $F$ is the desired isomorphism. I use the definition that an ordinal is any wellfounded transitive set of transitive sets; I'll let you figure out why this is equivalent to the definition you gave in the comments (hint: ordinals are wellordered by $\in$).
To prove that each $F(a)$ is an ordinal, take the inductive premise that all $b<a$ are such that $F(b)\in\mathbf{Ord}$. Since we have $F(a)=\{F(b) : b<a\}$ being a set of ordinals, then $F(a)$ is therefore a set of transitive sets. Next, given any $\gamma \in \beta\in F(a)$, there exists $b<a$ with $\beta=F(b)$, and since $\gamma\in F(b)$ then there's $c<b$ with $\gamma=F(c)$, but then $c<b<a$ implies $c<a$ so that $\gamma=F(c)\in F(a)$. It follows that $F(a)$ is also a transitive set. Just in case you don't assume the axiom of Foundation/Regularity, we also see that $F(a)$ is a set of wellfounded sets, and thus $F(a)$ is wellfounded too. Since $F(a)$ is a wellfounded transitive set of transitive sets, then $F(a)$ is an ordinal, which completes the induction.
Letting $\alpha=\{F(a) : a\in A\}$, now we can prove that $\alpha$ is an ordinal, and that $F:A\to \alpha$ is an order isomorphism. Similar to before, $\alpha$ is a set of ordinals and is thus a set of transitive sets, and moreover $\alpha$ is wellfounded. Whenever we have $\gamma\in\beta\in \alpha$, we can find $b\in A$ with $F(b)=\beta$, and then $c<b$ with $\gamma=F(c)$, and since $c\in A$ then $\gamma=F(c)\in \alpha$. It follows that $\alpha$ is a transitive set too, thus $\alpha$ is an ordinal. Since having $b<a$ implies $F(b) \in F(a)$, then $F:A\to \alpha$ is strictly increasing, and surjective, and therefore an order isomorphism.
